# In a Python List - How to retrieve a variable stored in a known position? Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I'm a Python beginner stuck on a simple issue. I might not be able to describe my issue clearly, but searching around hasn't been fruitful.

I have two nested lists in Python:

```
ny = []
bos = []
dc = []
mia = []
chi = []

ny = [bos, 'Boston', dc, 'Washington D.C.', chi, 'Chicago']
dc = [mia, 'Miami', chi, 'Chicago', ny, 'New York']
```

I wrote a function that prints every other item in a list, ie, just the human-readable values in these particular lists.

When I call the function like this:

```
print_stations(dc)
```

...it works normally:

```
1 .  Miami
2 .  Chicago
3 .  New York
```

But when I call it like this:

```
print_stations(ny[2])
```

...I get nothing.

Why isn't `ny[2] == dc` ? I'm sure I'm missing something very simple, but my Google skills seem to have failed me.

Comment: what your dc, boss etc contains??

Comment: it does look like an ordered Dictionary might be better than remembering indexes and offsets for specific data items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't store the name `dc` in the `ny` list. You stored *a reference to the same list object*.

You then *rebound* the name `dc` to point to a *new* list. The other reference still in the list didn't change with that.

Rather than create a new list for `dc`, alter it in-place. Add new entries to the existing list:

```
dc.extend([mia, 'Miami', chi, 'Chicago', ny, 'New York'])
```

or replace all elements in the list (which could be 0) with new contents:

```
dc[:] = [mia, 'Miami', chi, 'Chicago', ny, 'New York']
```

Comment: Thanks very much - that makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
dc = []
```

And then this:

```
ny = [bos, 'Boston', dc, 'Washington D.C.', chi, 'Chicago']
```

So you have put an empty list (`dc`) into your `ny` list. After that you reassign `dc` to something else, but the list at `ny[2]` is still the empty list you originally put in there.

Try assigning `dc` before you put it into `ny`, or try *modifying* `dc` instead of reassigning it.

Comment: That's absolutely my issue. Thanks very much for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The error here is that you are assigning "dc" a value after "ny" is defined.

You will get an empty list when you will try print_station(ny[2])`

```
>>>print_station(ny[2])
>>>[]
```

but if you write the code like this:

```
ny = []
bos = []
dc = []
mia = []
chi = []

dc = [mia, 'Miami', chi, 'Chicago', ny, 'New York']
ny = [bos, 'Boston', dc, 'Washington D.C.', chi, 'Chicago']

print_station(ny[2])
print_station()
print_station()
print_station(dc)
```

you will get the following output:

```
>>>[[], 'Miami', [], 'Chicago', [], 'New York']


   [[], 'Miami', [], 'Chicago', [], 'New York']
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

is you know the location, call the list and placed [Number here] within the brackets.
`list = ['Yellow', 'Red', 'blue']`

If you want to get the 2nd on in the list, this is number 1 in the list as python counts from 0.

```
print(list[1])
```

result:

```
>>'Red'
```